# Using TikZ in landscape mode?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to somehow use the tikzpicture environment in landscape mode ?

I usually encounter this problem with graphics with a large X-range and a small Y-range.

I provide below a typical pdf output that I would like to be able to produce directly with TikZ. Currently,
I can only do it by first printing two halves separately, gluing some printed paper and eventually scan.
  I also append the TikZ code that produces the two halves below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{4cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{6cm}

\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-3cm} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\centerline{\bf\Large Annexe 1}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) node (O) {};
\foreach \y in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50,10.60,10.70,10.80,10.90,11.00,11.10,11.20,11.30,11.40,11.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };
\foreach \y in {0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00,11.00}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };

\draw (O)++(1.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$2$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(1.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(2.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$4$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(2.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(3.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$6$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(3.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(4.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$8$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(4.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(5.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$10$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(5.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(6.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$12$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(6.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(7.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$14$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(7.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(8.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$16$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(8.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(9.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$18$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(9.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(10.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$20$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(10.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,0.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$-1$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,0.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);

\draw (O)++(-0.20,2.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$1$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,2.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,3.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$2$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,3.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,4.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$3$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,4.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,5.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$4$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,5.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,6.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$5$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,6.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,7.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$6$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,7.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,8.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$7$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,8.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,9.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$8$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,9.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,10.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$9$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,10.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,11.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$10$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,11.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(0.00,1.00) node {$\bullet$};
\draw[thick,->] (O)++(0.00,0.00) -- ++(0,12.04);
\draw (O)++(0.00,12.04) node [fill=white,anchor=south east] {$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (O)++(0.00,1.00) -- ++(11.00,0);
\draw (O)++(11.00,1.00) node [fill=white,anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw (O)++(0.00,1.00) node [fill=white,anchor=north west] {$O$};
\draw [thick] (O)++(0.00,4.06) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node (O) {};
\foreach \y in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50,10.60,10.70,10.80,10.90,11.00,11.10,11.20,11.30,11.40,11.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };
\foreach \y in {0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00,11.00}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.50,1.50,2.50,3.50,4.50,5.50,6.50,7.50,8.50,9.50,10.50}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };
\draw (O)++(0.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$20$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(1.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$22$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(1.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(2.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$24$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(2.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(3.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$26$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(3.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(4.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$28$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(4.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(5.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$30$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(5.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(6.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$32$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(6.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(7.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$34$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(7.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(8.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$36$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(8.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(9.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$38$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(9.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(10.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$40$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(10.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);



\draw[thick,->] (O)++(0.00,1.00) -- ++(11.00,0);
\draw (O)++(11.00,1.00) node [fill=white,anchor=north west] {$x$};

\draw [thick] (O)++(0.00,5.08) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01);

\end{tikzpicture}










\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try a coordinate transformation at the start fo your picture: `\begin{tikzpicture} \pgftransformcm{0}{1}{-1}{0}{\pgfpoint{0}{0}} \draw(0,0) -- (0,1); \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: There is a fine feature in the `\foreach` command, instead of `\foreach \x in {0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00}` we can use `\foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}`. The default step is 1 (a step is a difference between two numbers before the leaving dots), so we can even use `\foreach \x in {0,...,10}`, the cycle is all the same but the code is slightly harder to read.

Comment: Not related with your question but, did you considered using [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) for this kind of plots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `standalone` class, generate pdf from it, and after you can add it in your document as you want using commands:

`\includegraphics` for `pdf` or `\includestandalone` for your `tex` code with `\usepackage{lscape}` and  `\begin{landscape} \end{landscape}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Annexe}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Tikz.pdf}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\caption{Annexe}
\includestandalone[mode=buildnew,width=\linewidth]{Tikz.tex}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}


\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\addtolength{\textwidth}{4cm}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{6cm}

%\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2cm}
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-3cm} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

%\centerline{\bf\Large Annexe 1}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) node (O) {};
\foreach \y in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50,10.60,10.70,10.80,10.90,11.00,11.10,11.20,11.30,11.40,11.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };
\foreach \y in {0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00,11.00}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };

\draw (O)++(1.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$2$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(1.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(2.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$4$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(2.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(3.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$6$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(3.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(4.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$8$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(4.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(5.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$10$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(5.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(6.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$12$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(6.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(7.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$14$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(7.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(8.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$16$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(8.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(9.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$18$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(9.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(10.00,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$20$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(10.00,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,0.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$-1$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,0.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);

\draw (O)++(-0.20,2.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$1$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,2.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,3.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$2$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,3.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,4.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$3$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,4.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,5.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$4$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,5.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,6.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$5$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,6.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,7.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$6$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,7.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,8.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$7$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,8.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,9.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$8$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,9.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,10.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$9$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,10.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(-0.20,11.00) node [fill=white,anchor=east] {$10$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.20,11.00) -- ++(-0.4,0);
\draw (O)++(0.00,1.00) node {$\bullet$};
\draw[thick,->] (O)++(0.00,0.00) -- ++(0,12.04);
\draw (O)++(0.00,12.04) node [fill=white,anchor=south east] {$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (O)++(0.00,1.00) -- ++(11.00,0);
\draw (O)++(11.00,1.00) node [fill=white,anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw (O)++(0.00,1.00) node [fill=white,anchor=north west] {$O$};
\draw [thick] (O)++(0.00,4.06) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.04) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.03) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.02) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,-0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.00) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node (O) {};
\foreach \y in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50,10.60,10.70,10.80,10.90,11.00,11.10,11.20,11.30,11.40,11.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.00,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.00,1.10,1.20,1.30,1.40,1.50,1.60,1.70,1.80,1.90,2.00,2.10,2.20,2.30,2.40,2.50,2.60,2.70,2.80,2.90,3.00,3.10,3.20,3.30,3.40,3.50,3.60,3.70,3.80,3.90,4.00,4.10,4.20,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.50,7.60,7.70,7.80,7.90,8.00,8.10,8.20,8.30,8.40,8.50,8.60,8.70,8.80,8.90,9.00,9.10,9.20,9.30,9.40,9.50,9.60,9.70,9.80,9.90,10.00,10.10,10.20,10.30,10.40,10.50}
   {
     \draw (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };
\foreach \y in {0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00,11.00}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(0, \y) -- ++(10.50, 0);
   };
\foreach \x in {0.50,1.50,2.50,3.50,4.50,5.50,6.50,7.50,8.50,9.50,10.50}
   {
     \draw [thick] (O)++(\x, 0) -- ++(0, 11.54);
   };
\draw (O)++(0.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$20$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(0.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(1.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$22$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(1.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(2.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$24$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(2.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(3.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$26$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(3.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(4.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$28$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(4.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(5.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$30$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(5.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(6.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$32$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(6.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(7.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$34$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(7.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(8.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$36$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(8.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(9.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$38$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(9.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);
\draw (O)++(10.50,0.80) node [fill=white,anchor=north] {$40$};
\draw[thick] (O)++(10.50,1.20) -- ++(0,-0.4);



\draw[thick,->] (O)++(0.00,1.00) -- ++(11.00,0);
\draw (O)++(11.00,1.00) node [fill=white,anchor=north west] {$x$};

\draw [thick] (O)++(0.00,5.08) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.02) -- ++(0.02,0.01) -- ++(0.02,0.01);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Can one also have the luxury of having all the code in one single file ?

Comment: @user40960, better divide your code in parts. It would be more readable...`standalone` package is made for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{lscape}

%...

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%insert code here

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

watch out: `landscape` forces a new page

Comment: As you say, landscape forces a new page and all of the page must be in landscape mode. I would like part landscape, part non-landscape.

Comment: @user40960 you could also try rotating the figure, but personally I never went down that road.

Comment: Please try `afterpage` package, at least it will fill previous page with regular typeset material.